# Locale - how to get case-sensitive value?

Tags: java, locale, canonicalization

I have code like this:

```
import java.util.Locale;
Locale locale = new Locale("en_US");
```

When I wrote:

```
System.out.println(locale.toString());
```

it returns

```
en_us
```

not

```
en_US
```

is any way to get case-sensitive value?

Comment: Sergi's answer is correct: the language field is by definition case insensitive and the original case that you use is not stored.

Comment: And if you still want, then do this _System.out.println(locale.toString().replace("us", "US"))_; Since you are passing the language code

Answer (score 2):

Taken from [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html):
`The language field is case insensitive, but Locale always canonicalizes to lower case.`

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik No, it is the correct quote.  The constructor with 1 `String` argument only has a language argument.  Calling `getCountry()` will return null or empty string.